# LIBRARY_PATH environment variable not being used / read with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, fedora

My LIBRARY_PATH variable is exported, but I still have to pass the -L option to gcc in order to link to my library.

If I understand the GCC documentation correctly [3.20 Environment Variables Affecting GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html), the LIBRARY_PATH environment variable should be looked so that I only have to specify the -l option.

When I run

```
gcc -Wall cog.c -L$HOME/lib -lutil
```

the program is compiled, and I get an a.out as expected.

If I run

```
gcc -Wall cog.c -lutil
```

I get an undefined reference error.

As far as I can tell, I've properly exported the environment variable.

```
cassiopeia~> export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib
cassiopeia~> ls $LIBRARY_PATH 
libutil.a
```

Any clues?

For what it's worth, I'm using Fedora 23 64bit and gcc version 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6).

Comment: please try LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @zgrw `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is exclusively used by the dynamic loader `ld.so` to find dynamic libraries at run-time. It does not affect the compiler or linker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your distro probably is multilib-enabled. If this is the case, all path strings to libraries are expanded with the architecture for this machine (typically 32-bit or 64-bit). So, if you specify

> $HOME/lib

as your search path, multilib might expand it to

> $HOME/lib/x86_64-linux/4.6

or

> $HOME/lib/x86_32-linux/4.6

You can check if this is the case by invoking gcc once using

```
gcc --print-search-dirs
```

This makes gcc respond with all search paths in use for config and libraries.

Comment: There may be something to this, but: I have a multilib-enabled system and setting LIBRARY_PATH to tell gcc where to find libraries seems to work just fine, no $(arch) subdirectories required.

Comment: @davmac It actually depends how *multilib* is configured - My personal opinion is: It shouldn't touch a search path given with `-L`. On some distributions, it does, however.