# ld commend doesn't search LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: gcc, ld, library-path

In linux (like ubuntu), I set LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my bash.bashrc file. 
But it seems that ld command does not search for that path.
I run '$ ld -l --verbose'
and it only search for default paths defined in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
Why this happened? If I have to add -L option every time I compile, why $LIBRARY_PATH is needed? Or did I miss something?
Thanks.

Comment: Your answer may be in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172362/library-path-environment-variable-not-being-used-read-with-gcc

Answer (score 0):

LIBRARY_PATH is not used by the tool chain.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not used by `ld`, but by the dynamic linker/loader [`ld.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so).